# Removing CSS parameter in a child theme without losing responsiveness

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I've got a really messed up plugin css in wordpress that has this tag from it's css:

```
#id_name > div > div {
    width: 5%;
}
```

after using some php hook to insert custom content, the div that should have the 5% width has moved, and now this code ended up squashing one div from my code. (something like below)

```
<div id="id_name">
    <div>
         <div>
         <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-5 no-padding">
             /*CONTENT SQUASHED BY THE 5% WIDTH*/
         </div>
         <div>
              /*THE ORIGINAL DIV THAT WAS TARGETED BY THE CSS*/
         </div>
         </div> 
</div>
```

I'm trying to fix it without editing the plugin CSS, but every attempt I've made so far ended up in losing the columns responsiveness. (auto, 100%, inherit, initial, unset... (tried even 'none' and 'revert', that obviously is inappropriate...)

Is there any method to do this without touching the plugin code?
If anyone come up with any idea I'd appreciate!

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

override `css` with below code in your local css file

```
#id_name > div > div {
    width: 100%;
}
#id_name > div > div div:last-child {
    width: 5%;
    float: left
}
```

Comment: Thanks! that helped me a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Why not define a class or an id directly for the div that your are targeting? I'm not sure I fully understand what you are trying to accomplish, but if you are targeting just the

```
 <div>
     /*THE ORIGINAL DIV THAT WAS TARGETED BY THE CSS*/
 </div>
```

why not write:

```
 <div id = "id_name">
     /*THE ORIGINAL DIV THAT WAS TARGETED BY THE CSS*/
 </div>
```

instead? Also in the code you have uploaded, you have forgot the closing quotation marks for "id_name"

Comment: that's what I asked the plugin developer! 
It would work, but I don't have direct access to this div without editing the plugin core files.

The only content that I inserted from this code was this div:  `<div class="col-sm-10 col-md-5 no-padding">`

Comment: Okay I think I see your problem. For starters when you use this: #id_name > div > div {
    width: 5%;
} 
you're actually modifying the properties of the 3rd div which engulfs the two divs (the one you created and the one you want to modify). Additonaly, that seems to not work on the div you wish to modify which leads me to believe you simply do not have acess to it. In this scenario, you could try wrapping the content you want to modify inside that div in some <span> or another <div> and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

You are targeting the wrong level.

```
#id_name > div > div {
    width: 5%;
}
```

The above selector targets the **parent** `div` of **both** the `div` *you want to be* `5%` **and** *the one you don't want to be* `5%` wide

So, by squeezing the parent container the `<div class="col-sm-10 col-md-5 no-padding">` will only be `5%` wide - in relation to the grandparent container - even if your set it to `width:100%` because its parent container is only allowed to be `5%` wide

---

*Note: The way the CSS is written indicates laziness. The author should have added a `class` to the `div` to prevent such issues. I'd be mindful about the rest of the code of said plugin*

---

### Beyond that...

The "proper" way to target that `div` in your plugin would have been

```
#id_name > div > div > div
```

instead of

```
#id_name > div > div
```

It seems the styling that was intended for the **child** `div` or

```
#id_name > div > div > div
```

but was applied to its **parent** `div` or

```
#id_name > div > div
```

Since **the only modification** was the `width` it probably looked "right" or like it achieved the result.

The reason your responsiveness breaks is due to the fact that when you target

```
#id_name > div > div
```

like in your question you're changing the properties of the parent and probably push things around unintentionally.

Had the plugin author used

```
#id_name > div > div > div
```

that then this snippet below - or any other variation for selecting `<div class="col-sm-10 col-md-5 no-padding">` - would have fixed the issue.

```css
#id_name>div>div>div {
  width: 5%;
  background: blue;
}

#id_name>div>div>div[class] {
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="id_name">
  <div>
    <div>
      <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-5 no-padding">
        /*CONTENT SQUASHED BY THE 5% WIDTH*/
      </div>
      <div>
        /*THE ORIGINAL DIV THAT WAS TARGETED BY THE CSS*/
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: that's exactly what is happening.

Comment: I wasn't able to find a way to achieve this without modifying the plugins files due to lack of sleep! (and perhaps I haven't explained the problem here with enough information.)

I was able to fix it enclosing the ` <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-5 no-padding">` in another `<div class='col-md-12->` and then setting '#id_name>div>div> {width: 100%;}` in the child theme.

thanks for your kind explanation though! it helped me to figure it out! =]